# MySQL Multi update is inserting duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a PHP script that posts **many** `<select>` elements in order to update a schedule. Each user (6 digit ID) can select one of any locations (4 digit ID) *per day*. Here is what that looks like:

`$_REQUEST`

```
[
'2018-01-01'=>1234,
'2018-01-02'=>3456,
'2018-01-03'=>2345,
...
]
//The user's ID (`sid`) is missing from the request because a user
//can only update their own schedule; Their ID is stored in $_SESSION
```

I'd like it so that my SQL query can do all of the table manipulation in one query. The one caveat is that there can't be any duplicates in the table. **To be clear, by duplicate I mean that there should only be one record for a given day, *per user*.** So I've used the following query:

PHP + MySQL

```
$params = array();
$days = 0; //Count the number of days to update
foreach ($_REQUEST as $date => $id) {
  array_push($params,
    $_SESSION['sid'],
    $date,
    $id
  );
  $days ++;
}
$value_string = str_repeat("(?,?,?),", $days - 1). "(?,?,?)";
$sql = "INSERT INTO schedule_s (sid, date, plan) VALUES $value_string
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = VALUES(date), sid = VALUES(sid)";
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm still getting duplicates in my table. I'm finding it a little tricky to come up with a solution, since there are certainly going to be duplicate **sids** and **logs** in each column.

Here's the table layout.

```
sid    | date       | log
---------------------------
123456 | 2018-01-01 | 1234
123456 | 2018-01-02 | 3456
123456 | 2018-01-03 | 2345
...
567890 | 2018-01-01 | 5678
567890 | 2018-01-02 | 5678
567890 | 2018-01-03 | 2345
...
```

Any help on getting this update to work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate here?  Your sample data only seems to show a user can have only one entry per day.  But, your language seems to be implying something other than this.

Comment: I'll make an edit

Answer (score 1):

The immediate fix to your problem is to add a unique index on the combination of the `sid` and `date` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE schedule_s ADD CONSTRAINT cnstr UNIQUE (sid, date);
```

Then, if a user tries to submit a date which already has an entry, the query would fail at the database level.  Then, you could handle the failure in your PHP code.

But, from a user experience point of view, it would be good to load the page and presenting the user with only dates which are currently available.  A calendar table might come in handy here, which you could join to `schedule_s` to generate the available dates.

Comment: The user is freely allowed to change their schedule up until the actual day. The table's layed out from the beginning to the end of the year, so the query should always perform an update. The purpose then of using `INSERT` is simply to perform the update in one query. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @CurtisUpshall Allowing for updates complicates things, but the unique constraint I suggested should still part of the solution, I think.  I tried to cover the UI side because while you certainly _can_ rely on MySQL to detect duplicates, it would be better if you avoid presenting a drop down to your user which would result in a duplicate.

Comment: The fact that users can change theirs schedule before the day happens is a must. I suppose just making several UPDATE queries separated by semicolons will do the trick?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  Your question revolves around how to prevent duplicates from being inserted.  I have given one way of avoiding this, and also made a suggestion about how you should structure your UI.  This is as much as I can do.